# How to use a variable in an escape sequence?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to print out a series unicode characters, boxdrawing chars.
So far I tried

```
let myvar = 'f';
print!("\u{252{}}", myvar);
```

Obviously the compiler doesn't like it.
Where can I find information regarding my situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first argument to `print!` has to be a string literal, and you cannot nest the format tokens as you have already discovered, so the way you are currently trying to do it won't work.

If your objective is to print a unicode character in the range `0x2520` - `0x252f` where the variable `myvar` contains the last digit then I would suggest something like this:

```rust
// Suppose the input is hex digit '5', first convert to a u32
let myvar = '5'.to_digit(16).unwrap();

// Then add to the base and convert to a char
let uni_char = std::char::from_u32(0x2520 + myvar).unwrap();

// After that you can print it, append it to a string, or whatever
println!("{}", uni_char);
```

If you can arrange things so you are starting with an integer instead of a hex digit it is even simpler.

Answer (score 0):

In Rust strings, an unicode code point escape sequence is represented by `\u` followed by the code point itself, surrounded by braces.

For example, `'\u{7FF}'` represents the unicode character [NKO TAMAN SIGN](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/7ff/index.htm).

It is a **compile-time constant**. There is no way to interpolate a runtime value within an unicode escape sequence.

What you want to do is actually to print a `char` directly.

```
let nko = '߿';
print!("{}", nko);
```

or

```
let nko = '\u{7FF}';
print!("{}", nko);
```

which are equivalent.